# How can I select articles by categories in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm a beginner meteor. I create a blog with many posts(article) by each categories. This is my Collection:

```
if (Category.find().count() === 0) {
[
  {
    name: 'IT',
    sub_categories: [
      { name: 'Java' },
      { name: 'PHP' },
      { name: '.NET' },
      { name: 'Android/iOS' },
      { name: 'HTML/CSS' },
      { name: 'Javascript and Framworks' },
      { name: 'Ruby on Rails' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'ENGLISH',
    sub_categories: [
      { name: 'Listening' },
      { name: 'Speaking' },
      { name: 'Writing' },
      { name: 'Reading' },
      { name: 'Topic' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'SoftSkill',
    sub_categories: [
      { name: 'CV and CL' },
      { name: 'Presentation' },
      { name: 'Teamwork' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'ENTERTAINMENT',
    sub_categories: [
      { name: 'Sports' },
      { name: 'Games' },
      { name: 'Music & Videos' },
      { name: 'Fashion' },
      { name: 'Talk show' },
    ],
  },
].forEach(doc => {
  Category.insert(doc);
});
```

}

After I save all posts by each categories, Now I want to show it throught select option

[image]

**Details**:

When I click on "IT" button -> app show all sub_categories. Then I choose one option (example "Java") it will show all posts have `sub_categories` = "Java". Can you help me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use navbar for your requirement.

In that navbar you can have dropdown as navbar element
[Please Follow this steps if it is useful for  you](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html)